# jquery scroll ajax limit to one request

Tags: jquery, ajax, scroll

I have this code that will check for if the class more-results are in the viewport. And when it is it runs the ajax request.

```
    $(window).scroll( function() { 
        if ($("a.more-results:in-viewport").each(function()  {

            $.ajax({  
              type: 'GET',  
              url: $(this).attr('href'),
              data: args,
              success: function(response) {
                response = $.trim(response);
                if($('#more-results-link').length){
                    $('#more-results-link').remove();
                } else {
                    $('.more-results-link:visible').remove();
                }
                var $responseHTML = $(response).appendTo(ajaxElement);
                $responseHTML.find("input:checkbox").uniform({useID: false});
              }

            });

        }));
    });
```

and this works.. but... it fires several requests when scrolling...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should have a look at the [jQuery Masonry Plugin.](http://masonry.desandro.com/docs/intro.html). It allows you to create an [infinite page scroll effect](http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/infinite-scroll.html) like we see on [Facebook wall](http://facebook.com)...

Comment: Currently I only need this single feature and need to keep the js/css sizes to a minimum so adding all of these files is currently not an option :/